# Jackrabbit oak remove node doesn't freed disk space

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit-oak

So when I try to remove node it doesn't remove file from disk. Only node is removed. There is example of code what I do:

```
Node node = session.getNodeByIdentifier(uuid);
node.remove();
```

I read that garbage collector must be invoked to remove file from disk. I can't find how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of store.

For the DocumentNodeStore (Mongo, RDB), see http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/nodestore/documentmk.html#revision-gc.

For Segment store, see http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/nodestore/segment/overview.html#garbage-collection.